# PHP requests processing in serial not parallel

Tags: php, imaplib

I wrote a page (`cron.php`) that uses the imap library to connect to a mailbox, parse messages, and store them in a database, then `echo`s the results in json.  I have a few dozen mailboxes that I need to run this same process for, and so I put together a page (`mailboxes.php`) that lists all these accounts, each with a button that when clicked, essentially hits `cron.php` via AJAX and parses the json response to update the page when the process is completed.

I've noticed however that if I click each of these boxes, they return as if running serially, not in parallel.  Is there a configuration option someplace that might explain this?

Comment: You're using parallel programming via ajax. That's wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser http://www.openajax.org/runtime/wiki/The_Two_HTTP_Connection_Limit_Issue. You can only reliably hope to run 2 ajax requests at any time because of browser limitations.

Comment: Thank you.  This does also seem to be part of the problem. When I close the sessions they come back more quickly, but also seem to come in pairs.  Would this connection limit still be an issue if I invoked the php file via command line (e.g. `php cron.php`)?

Comment: Nope, you can start as many processes via command line as you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you need to use `session_write_close()` on the cron.php file. [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that sessions would lock.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using sessions? Every time you run `session_start` for given session, it is being locked, until the script finishes, or the session is being 'detached'.